# smartgit showing modified files with not changes

Tags: git

I'm generating certain files with a tool (I'm writing in C#), and I presume they must differ somehow comparing to the old ones, **except the text content should be the same**.

And smartgit shows them as **modified**, except when doing `File Compare` ( `F4` ), **there's no changes to show**.

I would prefer for them **not** to be shown as modified.

Comment: If Git shows them as modified, they are modified. Your comparison tool may be ignoring whitespace/EOL/unprintable characters.

Comment: To understand better the flag, see [Tracing the modified state of a file](https://docs.syntevo.com/SmartGit/HowTos/Tracing-the-modified-state-of-a-file.html). Question: If your program is writing a new file, why shouldn't it be marked as modified? It might only differ on the date.

Comment: @harrymc since the actual text content (it is C#/html code inside) didn't change, it doesn't matter for me that some EOL hidden character changed.

Comment: If the problem is the EOL, you could set `core.autocrlf` to `true` in `.gitconfig`.

Comment: @harrymc in my project `"root folder"/.git/config`, in the file content  under `[core]` I have  `autoclrf = true`
and `autocrlf = true` and it doesn't change anything

Comment: Try `core.autocrlf=input`.